# Python create a sublist with shuffled elements and reference by object

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pandas, pointers

I couldn't find an answer to my question through searching, so I hope you can help me.

I have a list which holds pandas DataFrame objects. Now I want to create two sublists from this list. Say I want to create two lists both with half the length of the original list. Every element can only appear in one list and can't appear more than once. The DataFrame objects are large, so I want to use only pointers. I want the list order to be shuffled.

Example: I have list `a` with the elements. To get a shuffled order of indices I can do the following (np refers to numpy):

```
shuffledElements = list(range(a.len()))
shuffledElements = np.random.shuffle(shuffledElements)
```

Now, how can I create two sublists with random order of elements but without copying the elements to the sublist but using pointers instead?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `shuffledElements` will be `None`, since `np.random.shuffle` is inherently an in-place operation and returns `None`.

Comment: @not_a_robot thank you. So I just write np.random.shuffle(shuffledElements) instead right?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I dont know if I understand you right. I want to do basically this: 1. shuffle the list 2. create two sublists but without copying. This should be possible right?

Comment: @Skyy2010 Yah I misunderstood your issue, ignore my previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is make a shallow copy of your list, shuffle it, an then create a list with one half of the elements and a list with the other half.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> shuffled = a[:] # shallow copy
>>> np.random.shuffle(shuffled) # shuffle in place
>>> left = shuffled[:len(shuffled)/2]
>>> right = shuffled[len(shuffled)/2:]
>>> left
[4, 3]
>>> right
[2, 1]
```

no data (except for references to integer objects somewhere in memory) has been copied.

```
>>> left[0] is a[3]
True
```

You could do the same with lists that hold ony kind of object, I just used integers for demonstration. (Of course, if your original list has an odd number of elements, you'll have to adjust the code, but that is besides the point here.)

Comment: Need floor division (`//`) for Python 3 but moreover `left` and `right` are actually copies here are they not?

Comment: To clarify, if you change `shuffled` at the end of this, `left` and `right` won't change

Comment: @Chris_Rands so, what about it? The objects to which the cells of each of those lists point to (in OP's case large dataframes) have never been copied.

Comment: Actually I think you're right, but was confused because your `is` example doesn't show anything because `int`s are cached in CPython between -5 and 256 anyway. However, the test holds with larger `int`s too.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah, I am aware of the integer caching, that's why it is important to point out that the code above would work with any kind of object in the original list `a`.

Comment: Ok, agreed, apologies for my misunderstanding; would still recommend floor division though